# Python: Random Password Generator

Tags: python

I want o create a Random Password generating program. Passwords shown should have a minimum of 10 digits to a maximum of 20 digits. However, the program didn't capture the length.

My code:

```
import random
import string

def rpassword():
    while True:
        length = int(input('\nEnter the length of password: '))
        if length < 10:
            print("\nWarning: Password length should be more than 10!")
        elif length > 20:
            print ("\nWarning: Password length should be less than 20!")
        else:
            print("\nYour password is: ", password)
            break

lower = string.ascii_lowercase
upper = string.ascii_uppercase
number = string.digits
symbol = string.punctuation

pswd = lower + upper + number + symbol

passd = random.sample(pswd,length)
password = "".join(passd)   

rpassword()

#exampleoutput
#Hello, Welcome to Random Password Generator!

#Enter the length of password: 15

#Your password is:  +|VR{c<$k
```

Comment: What do you mean *"didnt capture the length."*? `length` is only defined in the function, not in the global scope...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will work:

```
import string
import random

def rpassword():
    while True:
        length = int(input('\nEnter the length of password: '))
        if length < 10:
            print("\nWarning: Password length should be more than 10!")
        elif length > 20:
            print("\nWarning: Password length should be less than 20!")
        else:
            lower = string.ascii_lowercase
            upper = string.ascii_uppercase
            number = string.digits
            symbol = string.punctuation

            pswd = lower + upper + number + symbol

            passd = random.sample(pswd, length)
            password = "".join(passd)
            print("\nYour password is: ", password)
            break

rpassword()
```

output:

```
Enter the length of password: 15

Your password is:  cX7Mg<91G@0-.C"
```

Comment: thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to indent your code to have it happen inside the `rpassword` function (indent it so it's deeper than the `def` but not the `while`), and you also need to print the password *after* you've generated it, not before:

```
def rpassword():
    while True:
        length = int(input('\nEnter the length of password: '))
        if length < 10:
            print("\nWarning: Password length should be more than 10!")
        elif length > 20:
            print ("\nWarning: Password length should be less than 20!")
        else:
            break

    # At this point the loop has broken and 10 < length < 20.
    lower = string.ascii_lowercase
    upper = string.ascii_uppercase
    number = string.digits
    symbol = string.punctuation

    pswd = lower + upper + number + symbol

    passd = random.sample(pswd, length)
    password = "".join(passd)

    # Now we have a valid value for password!
    print("\nYour password is: ", password)

rpassword()
```

I might suggest having this function `return` the password and printing it outside the function -- that way if you want to *do* something with the password (like store it somewhere) it's easy to assign it to a value outside of the function instead of (or in addition to) printing it.

```
def rpassword() -> str:
    while True:
        length = int(input('\nEnter the length of password: '))
        if length < 10:
            print("\nWarning: Password length should be more than 10!")
        elif length > 20:
            print("\nWarning: Password length should be less than 20!")
        else:
            break

    return "".join(random.sample(
        string.ascii_lowercase
        + string.ascii_uppercase
        + string.digits
        + string.punctuation,
        length
    ))


print("\nYour password is: ", rpassword())
```